# Why does the object in this Objective C code not set?

Tags: objective-c

I have the below code which simply read a bunch of cards and inputs their names into a Mutable Array if they are not present beforehand.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableArray *allCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        char cardAvailable = '\0';
        do {
            Card *newCard = [[Card alloc] init];
            NSLog(@"What is the Card Name ?\n");
            char cName[20];
            scanf("%s",cName);
            NSString *nName = [NSString stringWithCString:cName encoding:1];
            [newCard setName:nName];
            if([newCard wasMatch:allCards]) {
                NSLog(@"Card Already Present");
            } else {
                NSLog(@" NEW CARD NAME %@ %@ %s",[newCard getName],newCard.name, cName);
                [newCard addGlobal:newCard toArray:allCards];
            }
            NSLog(@"Is there another Card to Input?");
            scanf("%c",&cardAvailable);
        } while(cardAvailable != 'N' || cardAvailable != 'n');

        NSLog(@":::: Card Names Are ::::");
        for(Card *card in allCards)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",card.name);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, first - The name is simply NOT SET. I don't know why this is happening. Today was my first day ever with Objective C, so please pardon me if this is too simple.

The Card class files are -

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Card : NSObject

    @property(nonatomic) BOOL chosen;
    @property (nonatomic, getter = getName) NSString *name;

    -(BOOL)wasMatch:(NSMutableArray*) allCards;
    -(void)addGlobal:(Card*) aCardName toArray:(NSMutableArray*) allCards;
    -(void)setName:(NSString *)name;
    -(void)setChosen:(BOOL)chosen;
@end
```

I get the error here - in the add global line.

```
#import "Card.h"

@implementation Card

@synthesize chosen = _chosen;

-(BOOL)chosen
{
    return _chosen;
}

-(void)setChosen:(BOOL)chosen
{
    _chosen = chosen;
}

@synthesize name = _name;

-(NSString*)getName
{
    return _name;
}

-(void)setName:(NSString*)name
{
    name = _name;
}

-(BOOL)wasMatch:(NSMutableArray *)allCards
{
    for(Card *card in allCards)
    {
        if([self.name isEqualToString:card.name])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

-(void)addGlobal:(Card *)aCardName toArray:(NSMutableArray *)allCards
{   NSLog(@" THE NS STRING %@",aCardName.name);
    [allCards addObject:aCardName.name];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setter is wrong.

```
-(void)setName:(NSString*)name
{
    name = _name;
}
```

You assign the current instance variable (_name) to the parameter.

This should be the other way around.

```
-(void)setName:(NSString*)name
{
    _name = name;
}
```

But you don't need this at all. There are various problems with your code.

- Objective-C does not use getFoo for ordinary getters.
  `@property (nonatomic, getter = getName) NSString *name;` should be
  `@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;`

And unless you are writing code in a ancient version of Objective-C (which you shouldn't) you don't need explicit getters and setters. In recent version you don't even have to explicitly synthesize.
In newer version of Objective-C your Card class should look more like this:

```
@interface Card : NSObject

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL chosen;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;

-(BOOL)wasMatch:(NSMutableArray*) allCards;
-(void)addGlobal:(Card*) aCardName toArray:(NSMutableArray*) allCards;
@end

#import "Card.h"

@implementation Card

-(BOOL)wasMatch:(NSMutableArray *)allCards
{
    for(Card *card in allCards)
    {
        if([self.name isEqualToString:card.name])
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}

-(void)addGlobal:(Card *)aCardName toArray:(NSMutableArray *)allCards
{   NSLog(@" THE NS STRING %@",aCardName.name);
    [allCards addObject:aCardName.name];
}

@end
```

Way less code. You might want to look for a more up to date learning resource.

The rest of your code looks questionable as well. I honestly don't see the point in  `addGlobal:toArray:`. But I don't want to make this answer longer than necessary. ;-)

---

Also, for the love of your future self, don't use 1 in `NSString *nName = [NSString stringWithCString:cName encoding:1];` use the constant. In your case `NSASCIIStringEncoding`. But because it's no longer 1980 you most likely want to use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead of ASCII.

As I said, please get more recent and decent learning resources.

Comment: Great Answer. Thanks a lot. Any resource you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

In the `-setName:` property accessor method, you assign the the `_name` instance variable value to the `name` parameter. It should be swapped like this:

```
-(void)setName:(NSString*)name
{
    _name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To learn Objective-C i reccomment the most recent Stanford lectures by Paul Hegarty. CS193p the class is called. You can find all materials, and excellent videos on iTunes U. Other then Apple resource, there is no better then this.

Comment: This is actually what he does in the first lecture in fact. I thought I'd implement some of it.